# Can video.js tell me when the "scrub" widget is dragged?

Tags: video.js

That is, is there an event that video.js fires when the scrub widget is dragged and (in particular) released?  This would presumably be like "paused", but work off the scrub widget?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? You may be able to use player.on('mousemove'), and check that the event.target matches the scrub handle

Comment: I'm trying to get the frame position of the scrubber after it is dragged to some place in the video -- the page containing the player will get submitted, and some stuff utilizing the frame position will happen.  I may be able to get away with calling `currentTime` as part of the submit process and converting it to frames, but I thought I'd check into how accessible the scrubber is.  Meanwhile, I'll try to look into the mousemove idea.

Comment: I want to respond to this event also. So far, the best I've come up with is to listen for the **timeupdate** event and track the last video_time reported. If the latest currentTime is less than video_time, that suggests someone has gone back (i.e., rewound) the video a bit. Catching fast forward is harder...then currentTime would have to exceed video_time by some threshold. Don't know what that threshold should be.